# How to use ajax in PHP foreach?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, ajax

I have a form with two select html tags and an input submit. To populate the value of option tags and to display the equivalent values of selected option tag, I use PHP, please see snippet below.

Now, I want to use AJAX using JS to avoid the reloading of the browser when the user clicked the button. But I don't know how. Please help me

Here's the [link](http://www.homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/4988-2/oppo-f1-at-0-interest/)

Snippet:

```
if(isset($_POST['mall_list'])){
    $mall_list= $_POST['mall_list'];
    $malls= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT stores FROM tablename WHERE malls = '" . $mall_list. "' GROUP BY stores ORDER BY stores", OBJECT));

    echo '<div class="\record\">';
    foreach ($malls as $record){
        echo '<div>' . $record->stores . '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';

} elseif(isset($_POST['store_list'])){
    $store_list= $_POST['store_list'];
    $stores= $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT malls FROM tablename WHERE stores= '" . $store_list. "' GROUP BY malls ORDER BY malls", OBJECT));

    echo '<div class="\record\">';
    foreach ($stores as $record){
        echo '<div>' . $record->malls. '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This is a very basic question. Please try something with ajax and come back with the code. https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/

Answer (score 3):

if you want to post data through ajax jquery. this code work for you.

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "your post url",
                data: $('#yourformname').serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: and how to call that ajax in php foreach?

Comment: $data = $_POST['data'] or $_REQUEST['data'] and then json_decode($data); You extract the data from the form --> post it via ajax to php backend --> process data via the foreach

Comment: can you create a example how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="ajax-form-submit.php" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value =""/> <br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value ="" /> <br/>
    Email : <input type="text" name="email" value=""/> <br/>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//callback handler for form submit
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            //data: return data from server
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            //if fails      
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});

$("#ajaxform").submit(); //Submit  the FORM
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
$("#form").submit(function(e){
   var data = $(this).serialize();
   var url = $(this).attr("action");
   $.post({
       url,
       data,
       function(res)
       {
           if(res.code == 0)
           {
               //success
               //code somthing when the server response
               alert(res.message);

           }
       }
   });
})
```

server

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    #is ajax request
    # code your business logic

    #response data 
    $response = [
       'code' => 0,
       'message' => 'success',
       'data' => []
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);exit;
} else {
    #is normal request
}
```